# On downloading a file, I get a response from web API call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

In my code I'm doing a call to an api that should answer me with a file (excel), I want to save this file in my pc,  I tryed many solutions provided here but nothing seems to work for me

```
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, stringContent).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {


                string results = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                byte[] toBeReturned = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<byte[]>(results);
                log.Info("downloadMasterList FINISH");
                return File(toBeReturned, "application/octet-stream");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

After you get the response (assuming you are getting `byte[]`), you need to save it to a local drive. You can use [File.WriteAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=netframework-4.8) to save.

```
var saveDir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "some_excel.xlsx");
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
        File.WriteAllBytes(saveDir, content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `WebClient` with `DownloadFileAsync` method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebClient_DownloadFileAsync_System_Uri_System_String_